# SQL Select all rows from table with lowest ids that match

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like so:

```
    id  |  order_id  |  product_id
------------------------------------
    1   |  356       |  80
    2   |  356       |  81
    3   |  357       |  77
    4   |  357       |  80
    5   |  357       |  78
    6   |  358       |  90
```

What I would like to be able to do is to grab the 2 lowest `order_id` values without knowing how many there are to begin with, but I am having trouble thinking of how to create the query to select these rows...

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY order_id ASC`

Is there a way to do this within MySQL, that will always return the lowest `order_id` value rows, so in this case, I should get the first 2 rows returned.  If the first 2 rows didn't exist, than I should get returned rows 3 - 5 (totaling 3 rows for order id 357).

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate functions can be used in the `HAVING` clause of a query, so you should be able to get all rows where the `order_id` matches the lowest `order_id` value using the `MIN` function in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table
HAVING order_id = MIN(order_id)
```

Comment: Quite simple and straightforward. Need a clear thought process to write it.

Comment: If the table is empty, does this still return empty result?  Sorry for the stupid question here...lol

Comment: @SolomonClosson - I'm not sure, and doing a little digging to find documentation, I'm now wondering if `HAVING` is actually meant to be only used for a `GROUP BY` context and this is an example of where MySQL allows for non-strict SQL queries (not sure this is actually the case, this may be totally SQL compliant, but can't find a firm source to confirm)-- but it will work in mysql in normal, non-strict contexts, so it is a valid answer (just maybe not the most ideal answer when considering stricter contexts).

Comment: hhhmm, ok, I'll give it a shot and hope it works.  Thanks

Comment: This wasn't very helpful and caused error, but thanks just the same.  I ended up ordering by order_id ASC and just limiting the result to about 5 and seems to be ok, but would've rather been able to get all products associated with an order_id value.  Oh well, thanks just the same.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

---

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
table INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MIN(order_id) AS min_order_id
    FROM table
) AS t
ON t.order_id = table.order_id;
```

- First get the minimum order id and give it an alias `t`.
- Now Make an `inner join` between your `table` and this `alias t` ON
  `order_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select *
from yourtable
where order_id in (
    select order_id from yourtable order by order_id ASC limit 1
)
```

Or use `join`

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
join (select order_id from yourtable order by order_id ASC limit 1) t2
on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
```